# I am getting an error with React.js and Typescript with spread operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs

Please help me with my situation. I tried doing typescript where I used useReducer hook.

```
const initialState = {
    a: "a"
};

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {...initialState});
```

I constantly get error at the spread operator.
The error that I get is

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction<any>, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: any, action: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: any, action: any) => void, initialState: void, initializer?: undefined): [void, Dispatch<any>]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.
```

What does this mean??

my .babelrc file looks like this

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
}
```

Where did I go wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `reducer` needs to output a value of the same type as `initialState`. Currently `reducer` outputs nothing (`void`), and that's why you are seeing this error.